# How can I install Gangal's font in Linux?

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-font-family

I use `Sopi Marathi` software in Windows for Marathi Typing. But I unable to read that font into Linux. How can I install `Gangal's` font in Ubuntu?? 
[image]
I read http://techblog.shyamjoshi.in/2013_01_01_archive.html

And also where I got Open Source Backup of that Fonts for Linux because Gangals.com in not available now.

Comment: You should include in your question what you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: @DKBose I try it by two way... 1. I install `Baraha Pad` 2. also Install `sopi marathi` by using wine. But when copy content into Libre Office then style of font it automatically change to by default Linux font. And also gangals.com not working now. So new problem is where I get that fonts from open source community? Any backup available for that fonts in Open Source Community?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need Gangal's font? Any missing symbols in the default fonts?

Comment: @muru Actually I need it because of font style and it based on Unicode. no missing any symbol  as per my knowledge. But I want variety of fonts for better presentation.

Comment: I don't know if the TTF files given in https://sites.google.com/site/gangalgsite/Home are the fonts you're looking for (or if they're safe to install), but you might want to check them.

Comment: @muru I install that three ttf fonts but they are not Unicode. Its different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve that by following steps.
**Step1:-** I copy Gangal's fonts from /home/your_username/.wine/drive_c/windows/fonts folder. (I was already installed Baraha and Sopi marathi) or [यॆथुन आपण गांगल फाॅन्ट डाउनलॊड करु शकता.you can download it from here.](http://www.mediafire.com/download/toavn182faoddcv/gangal%27s_font_%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%B2_%E0%A4%AB%E0%A4%BE%E0%A5%85%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9F.7z)
[image]
**step2:-** open terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
नंतर आपल्या संगणकात टर्मीनल उघडा. टर्मीनल उघडण्यासाठी <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> असॆ एकाच वॆळी टाईप करा. 
नंतर टर्मीनलमध्यॆ पुढील कमांड टाईप करा.
**step3:-** type command in terminal **`sudo -H nautilus`**
**`sudo -H nautilus`** असॆ टर्मीनलमध्यॆ टाईप करा. नंतर एक फॊल्डर ओपन हॊईल.

[image]
**step4:-** open folder /usr/share/fonts and copy Gangal's fonts into that folder.
ओपन झालॆल्या फॊल्डरमध्यॆ /usr/share/fonts ही फॊल्डर शॊधून त्यात फाॅन्टस् टाका.
**step5:-** after copy close fonts folder close terminal.
नंतर टर्मीनल व ओपन झालॆली फॊल्डर बंद करा.

[image]

Gangal's fonts in Open Office Linux.
ओपन आॅफिस मधील गांगल फाॅन्ट
my source :- [How to open /usr/share/fonts folder into graphical root privilege?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715719/how-to-open-usr-share-fonts-folder-into-graphical-root-privilege?noredirect=1#comment1055930_715719)